# android testing AVD with local hosts file

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, android-virtual-device

I new to using Xamarin AVD and I'm curious how to get it to pay attention to my `/etc/hosts` file. I'm on a Mac so I'm used to the iPhone Simulator doing this seemlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin AVD is the same as the Google AVD, with AVD meaning Android Virtual Device. In that way, all information that applies to the Android AVD also applies to those distributed with Xamarin.

With that said, the emulator does not use your local host file. However, you can send a copy of your host file to the emulator. You can do that with a few ads (Android Debug Bridge) commands. You will want ensure that the target emulator is running before you attempt these commands.

1. download a copy of the host file from the emulator with

`adb pull /system/etc/hosts /users/username/Desktop`

2. Edit the host file to match what is in your /etc/hosts file
3. Push the edited host file back to the emulator via:

`adb push /users/username/Desktop/hosts /system/etc`

And this should allow you to access local resources or modified hosts

Thanks!

Source: http://www.bradcurtis.com/hosts-files-and-the-google-android-emulator/

Comment: `failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': Read-only file system`
Doesn't works, you just copied & pasted from the blog.